# How to test Database methods in Apache jmeter?

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

I am trying to test some JDBC methods using apache jmeter like getFunctions. I have successfully created DB connection and executed a query to create one function. 
Now I wanted to test the output of getFunctions method. For this I am using JDBC Request Sampler. I have done below configuration for the JDBC request Sampler to test this method [image]

When I run this Test I am getting below error

> Response message: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: [XXXX][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'NULL'.

I tried 'NULL' , "NULL" and $NULL$ but all are giving same exception.

Can someone please guide me how can I test such methods using JDBC request in Apache Jemeter

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from [getFunctions()](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd571249(v=sql.105).aspx) method description it is applicable to [DatabaseMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) therefore unfortunately you won't be able to use JDBC Request sampler for testing this method.

The solution would be switching to [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) language, the relevant code would be something like:

```
def conn = org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement.getConnection('foo')
def resultSet = conn.getMetaData().getFunctions(null,null,null)
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter JDBC get functions]

Comment: I tried JSR223 Sampler with below code  `def conn = org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement.getConnection('test1')
def resultSet = conn.getMetaData().getFunctions(null,null,null)
def resultSetMetaData = resultSet.getMetaData()
log.info('out put is ' + resultSet)`  but in the log I can see it is printing the connection URL. In my code 'test1' in def conn is my jdbc connection configuration name. Can you please suggest what is the mistake here

Comment: In order to get your connection URL you need something like: `log.info('My URL is: ' + org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement.getConnection('test1').getMetaData().getURL())`  https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOHPt.png. I would also recommend checking out [Using JDBC Sampler in JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733769-Using-JDBC-Sampler-in-JMeter) article for more information on databases load testing using JMeter's JDBC Test Elements

Comment: Thank for the reply , my question here is how can I test JDBC metadata methods like getFunctions or getProcedures. I tried this set of code `def conn = org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement.getConnection('test1') def resultSet = conn.getMetaData().getFunctions(null,null,null) def resultSetMetaData = resultSet.getMetaData() log.info('out put is ' + resultSet)` But in log it is printing the Connection URL. This I dont want. I want to print the getFunctions method output